# Why are Graphics2D rectangles not displayed?

Tags: java, graphics2d, drawrectangle

I need to be able to display filled rectangles for the program i am creating, however the following code produces the following GUI with only the black text 'test' after calling start then change, could anyone explayin why please?

```
package core;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GUI extends JFrame{

private Graphics2D g;
private int[][][] clickable;

public void start(){

    this.setSize(500, 500);
    this.setTitle("Placeholder");
    this.setVisible(true);
    g = (Graphics2D) this.getGraphics();
}       

public void change(String[] fields, int type[], boolean forwards){
    g.setColor(new Color(28,35,57));
    g.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    g.drawRect(50, 50, 150, 150);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    g.drawString("test", 300, 300);     
}
}
```

And here is what it looks like ..

[image: output]

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2jkE.png

Comment: Custom painting shouldn't rely on the `Graphics` object you get with `getGraphics()` , override `paintComponent` instead .

Comment: Berger is correct, but for your example thing: have you tried **different** colours? Like changing the color between each call?

Comment: @GhostCat having changed the code to     g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
  g.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
  g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
  g.drawRect(50, 50, 150, 150);
  g.setColor(Color.RED);
  g.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
  g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
  g.drawString("test", 300, 300); the final result is the text at the end being green, so the draw functions seem to still not be working, ill try using the paintComponent instead

Comment: I have found that the draw rectangles do work if i draw them to a `JPanel` on the main `JFrame`, rather than drawing them straight to the `JFrame`. Also in regards to @Berger's comment, i've found that i should override the `PaintComponent()` as this is the function called whenever the window is resized/maximized etc. so whenever that happens, the window will go blank as it calls the `PaintComponent()` again

Answer (score 2):

Drawing on Swing components (like JFrame) works only in onPaint event.
The event can be fired using repaint() method.
This event fires automatically when frame needs to be painted.
To implement this event behavior override paint() method.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GUI extends JFrame{

    private Graphics2D g;

    public void start(){
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setTitle("Placeholder");
        this.setVisible(true);
    }       

    public void change(){
        g.setColor(new Color(28,35,57));
        g.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
        g.drawRect(50, 50, 150, 150);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
        g.drawString("test", 300, 300);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g2d){
        g = (Graphics2D) g2d;
        change();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        GUI frame = new GUI();
        frame.start();
    }

}
```